# W.A.C. feature enabling prevented by "MultiPoint Repair Service"

Tags: ssh, permissions, linux-networking, group-policy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Win 10 Pro(Activated)
Device Owner: Myself(as Administrator Account)
Version:22H2
HP EliteBook
Toshiba Satellite
-I run 2 copies of Win 10 Pro **both are activated and legitimate.**
-I have not attempted to enable features on the Toshiba Satellite, but assume the same issues would occur.

I was trying to enable Subsystem for Linux
add my account as a User for the SSH feature
and update User-Group Policies...
Rebooted to allow changes, then "MultiPoint Repair Service" reversed the changes made\

Is there a way to override MultiPoint Repair, without fully disabling it?
or
Am I just going about enabling aforementioned features the wrong way, for instance useing PowerShell instead of WAC

Comment: My Main account is tied into my Microsoft account, and logs in as Admin by default. This is reflected in WAC before attempting changes, so permissions should be good... I would assume.